# Bing Search API with Ajax

Tags: ajax

Trying to make fast queries to the Bing search API (azure marketplace).

The goal is to call the bing api and return the search results to the page. However, I need to make it really fast, possibly as fast as the end-user search on bing.com. Here is my code:

```
<div id="id01"></div>

<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/SearchWeb/v1/Web?Query=%27martin%27",
  password:"XXXXXXXXXXXX", 
  success: function(data){ 
  $("id01").html(data); 
 }
});
</script>
```

The password is filled with my account key. User should be blank. The above code does not return a result - not sure why. I included Ajax.

I'm aware of same-origin policy, but I assume for the API they set appropriate X-headers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be problem with your ajax call, try doing it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "your-url",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic bHVpZ2lAZ21haWwuY29tOmFiYzEyMzQ1');
         },
        success: function(data){ 
                  $("id01").html(data); 
         },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                 console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
         }

    })
```

Where second field inside xhr.setRequestHeader() is calculated as follows:

1. The username and password are combined into a string separated by a
   colon, e.g.: username:password
2. The resulting string is encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.
3. The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.

For example, if the user agent uses Aladdin as the username and OpenSesame as the password then the field is formed as follows:

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l
```

In your case you may need to use your api key as username as well as password both.